# Converting List of List (nested list) into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested, timedelta

I have a nested list, where each 'nested list' are grouped by 10 minutes interval (using timedelta function).

```
print(groups)
-----------------------results---------------------------
[[[1, Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:54:27')]],
 [[2, Timestamp('2019-01-22 08:37:04')]],
 [[3, Timestamp('2019-01-22 10:57:40')],
  [4, Timestamp('2019-01-22 10:57:43')]],
 [[5, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:09:07')],
  [6, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:18')],
  [7, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:23')],
  [8, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:25')]],
 [[9, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:35:03')],
  [10, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:35:35')]]...
```

These were information originally from a full dataframe. I am trying to convert this nested list into a dataframe format, with a seperate column named "Group". This means that the first 'nested list' would be group 1, and 2nd 'nested list' would be group 2.

Was thinking of transforming to dictionary before transforming to dataframe. However, they do not work too.

```
{k:row[0] for row in groups for k in row[1:]}
dict((k[0], k[1:]) for k in groups)
error: unhashable type: 'list'
```

All in all, I hope to write a function that automates my process as shown below:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(groups[1],columns=['index','datetime'])
df_1['group']=1

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(groups[2],columns=['index','datetime'])
df_2['group']=2

df_3 = pd.DataFrame(groups[3],columns=['index','datetime'])
df_3['group']=3
... etc...
```

Would love to hear how you guys would approach this issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you're trying to achieve?

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64100719#main.py)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

l = [
 [[1, Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:54:27')]],
 [[2, Timestamp('2019-01-22 08:37:04')]],
 [[3, Timestamp('2019-01-22 10:57:40')],
  [4, Timestamp('2019-01-22 10:57:43')]],
 [[5, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:09:07')],
  [6, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:18')],
  [7, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:23')],
  [8, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:16:25')]],
 [[9, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:35:03')],
  [10, Timestamp('2019-01-22 11:35:35')]],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [e1 + [g] for g, e0 in enumerate(l) for e1 in e0],
    columns = ['id', 'time', 'group'],
)

print('As one DataFrame:\n', df)

dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        [e1 + [g] for e1 in e0],
        columns = ['id', 'time', 'group'],
    )
    for g, e0 in enumerate(l)
]

print('\nAs separate DataFrames:')

for df in dfs:
    print('---------------------')
    print(df)
```

Outputs

```
As one DataFrame:
    id                time  group
0   1 2019-01-22 00:54:27      0
1   2 2019-01-22 08:37:04      1
2   3 2019-01-22 10:57:40      2
3   4 2019-01-22 10:57:43      2
4   5 2019-01-22 11:09:07      3
5   6 2019-01-22 11:16:18      3
6   7 2019-01-22 11:16:23      3
7   8 2019-01-22 11:16:25      3
8   9 2019-01-22 11:35:03      4
9  10 2019-01-22 11:35:35      4

As separate DataFrames:
---------------------
   id                time  group
0   1 2019-01-22 00:54:27      0
---------------------
   id                time  group
0   2 2019-01-22 08:37:04      1
---------------------
   id                time  group
0   3 2019-01-22 10:57:40      2
1   4 2019-01-22 10:57:43      2
---------------------
   id                time  group
0   5 2019-01-22 11:09:07      3
1   6 2019-01-22 11:16:18      3
2   7 2019-01-22 11:16:23      3
3   8 2019-01-22 11:16:25      3
---------------------
   id                time  group
0   9 2019-01-22 11:35:03      4
1  10 2019-01-22 11:35:35      4
```

Comment: YES! Brilliant, thank you. Still grasping the python language and there's many things I don't know. :)

Comment: @Laz Also just now added second part of code for representing as a list of small dataframes, one per group. For the case if you need small and many dataframes, one per group (it is not very obvious from your answer which of these two cases you needed). First part creates one big dataframe including all groups.

Comment: Yeap, what I was looking for is actually the first. However, I think it's always great to let others benefit from your second answer. Thx!